# Error in polymorphism?

Tags: java, android, polymorphism

`SimpleCursorAdapter` is an indirect subclass of `CursorAdapter` as stated in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html). But

```
CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(bla, bla, bla);
```

yields error from the compiler:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from SimpleCursorAdapter to CursorAdapter
```

Yet this has no errors:

```
abstract class  A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class C extends B {
}

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A c = new C();
    }
}
```

Is the documentation simply wrong, or am I missing something?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please show us your import statements. There are a lot of CursorAdapters in the Android API, you may have imported the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks, it's that, imported the wrong CursorAdapter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that you've got another type called `SimpleCursorAdapter` or `CursorAdapter` somewhere - check your import statements. You should be importing `android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter` and `android.widget.CursorAdapter`.

Comment: it's amazing how often people say "this <insert language feature here> is not working".   If you start your question with that, your code is most likely the source of the problem, not the language.

Comment: Thanks Jon for your time, that was it. @Matt: first, I never said *"polymorphism is not working"*, but *"Is the documentation simply wrong, or am I missing something?"* referring to Android's documentation. I knew the error had to be mine, not Java's, that's why I'm asking here. And second, if you're not posting something constructive, abstain useless (and in this case totally wrong) criticism and chit-chatting.

Comment: I think that in more than 95% of the cases the error is in the user, not in the language.